# Does the term "row set" and "row" have different meaning in the SQL vocabulary?

Tags: sql, relational-database, definition, relational-algebra

Consider the relation `enrolled(student, course)` in which `(student, course)` is the primary key, and the relation `paid(student, amount)` where `student` is the primary key. Assume no null values and no foreign keys or integrity constraints.
Given the following four queries:

Query1:

```SQL
select student from enrolled where student in (select student from paid)
```

Query2:

```SQL
select student from paid where student in (select student from enrolled)
```

Query3:

```sql
select E.student from enrolled E, paid P where E.student = P.student
```

Query4:

```SQL
select student from paid where exists 
    (select * from enrolled where enrolled.student = paid.student)
```

Which one of the following statements is correct?

(A) All queries return identical **row sets** for any database

(B) Query2 and Query4 return identical **row sets** for all databases but there exist databases for which Query1 and Query2 return different **row sets**

(C) There exist databases for which Query3 returns strictly fewer **rows** than Query2

(D) There exist databases for which Query4 will encounter an integrity violation at runtime

---

This question which is otherwise simple, I am having an issue with it in the sense that if we consider the meaning of the two terms "row sets" and "rows" to be equivalent, then we get one answer, but if we consider that they have a different meaning then we get another answer.

Now few of my peers [here](https://gateoverflow.in/1846/gate-cse-2006-question-68) are of the opinion that the term "row sets" and "rows" have different meanings. They say that in SQL when we alter a table we get the prompt that `x rows affected`. So in SQL, the tuples in a table are called rows (where duplicates are allowed). While "row set" is the collection of tuples in a table with duplicates removed, based on the set theory concept (or relational algebra concept).

While other peers are of the opinion that the term "row sets" and "rows" mean the same. They say that in SQL when we output a table we get the prompt that `x rows in set`. They say that in SQL the terms "row sets" and "rows" are used interchangeably.

Personally, I feel that they mean the same. But I am not sure. Please can anyone confirm?

Comment: This is partly a question about English, not SQL. "returns strictly fewer rows" means returns a row set with fewer members. (And "strictly" is redundant.) It's not in general meaningful to talk about word meanings or words "meaning the same" independent of usage.

Comment: The SQL "row set" query result here is **not a set of row values**. It's not clear which is meant, either a bag of row values or a list of row values. A query returns a list of row values. It's not clear whether here "row set" ignores the order (giving a bag) or not (giving a list). Writing about SQL is chronically horribly sloppy. PS Unadorned "row" can mean a row value or an instance of a row value or a row-valued variable--ask the speaker/writer. And French toast is not toast. (And not French.) **Give the reference for SQL used by this quote & its definition of "row set".**

Comment: They seem to mean bag not list because otherwise the choices are all false.

Comment: @philipxy `...can mean a row value or an instance of a row value or a row-valued variable` Please can you give a short example of what you mean by `instance of row value` or `row-valued variable` I could not get that part. And (hence) could not get the French toast example. 

Comment: Well, is French toast toast? Language is slippery. Re "row", it's similar to, say, "integer". When one says they have two integers they might mean two values, which must be different, since otherwise there would only be 1 value; or they might say it when they have two sixes, so two instances of the value six; and they might sloppily mean a variable or constant that holds an integer. In SQL in particular "table" is used sloppily for table value or a base table ie table-valued variable. Always distinguish value vs variable & the exact data type to be clear. PS Your SQL reference please.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the explanation. I got it now. `Your SQL reference please`. I do not get this statement... If you are asking about the source of the above question (the 4 queries in SQL followed by 4 options), then it came in an examination - GATE for CS in the year 2006

Comment: And GATE tells you that it says it is using what SQL references? In my last comment I was referring to my comment before that. ("row set" is not a official SQL technical term. "result set" is. And it isn't a set, it's a list.)

Comment: @philipxy https://gate.iitkgp.ac.in/documents/gatesyllabus/cs_2022.pdf (Thought the syllabus is of 2022, the original syllabus of 2006 is actually hard to find, but I guess the syllabus of the DBMS section has supposedly undergone no change) This the GATE syllabus for CS. In the DBMS section, they only mention `SQL`. Nothing more. Probably they mean standard SQL... The so called standard SQL which most college textbooks deal with... PS. GATE itself does not name any textbooks

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS It does seem GATE doesn't currently list textbooks. PS So unfortunately they are using a non-standard term reminiscent of a SQL standard term where both use a root term differently from the other & from its everyday meaning. Typical of SQL culture.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a reference and definition for what your "peers" are saying. SQL is a corruption of relational theory, which is why SQL has 'rows' or 'records', not 'tuples'. Some queries in SQL can return duplicate rows ('bags' not 'sets') so I would avoid 'set' wrt SQL except where your query has explicit `SELECT DISTINCT` or the tables have declared keys such that you can be sure the result is a set.

> `(student, course)` is the primary key, ... `student` is the primary key ... Assume no null values and no foreign keys or integrity constraints.

A primary key *is* an integrity constraint. I presume you mean no other constraints.

So the set of `student` values appearing in `enrolled` bears no connection to the set of `student` values appearing in `paid`. A given `student` value might appear in both or only one or only the other. `student` alone is not the primary key for `enrolled` so there might be repeated `student` values there. So

> (A) All queries return identical row sets for any database

Some of those queries are liable to return duplicate rows (because they don't have `SELECT DISTINCT`. So False: not all queries return sets.

If you mean all queries report an identical set of `student` values for any database in which the schema holds: True. (Test that by using `SELECT DISTINCT` for all cases.)

> (B) Query2 and Query4 return identical row sets ...

The q seems to be drawing on some subtle sense of 'row sets' that I'm not going to guess at. In general SQL queries do not return 'sets'. Avoid the term.

> (C) There exist databases for which Query3 returns strictly fewer rows than Query2

I wouldn't like to guess. It depends very much on the particular DBMS and how it optimises queries wrt primary keys.

> (D) There exist databases for which Query4 will encounter an integrity violation at runtime

False. Queries do not encounter integrity violations. It's only updates that can break integrity.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked by the post.